# Google Closure *.bat for post-build?

Tags: javascript, google-closure

Just wondering how I would prepare [or if anyone already has some code they can share] for a *.bat or *.exe tool for Google Closure online ? I'm trying to simply run a *.bat file with a list of javascripts

```
/path/js1.js
/path/js2.js
/path/js3.js
```

Which would send to the Google Closure API and then compress this list of files ? It will allow for easier monitoring and updating ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to run an EXE you can use the command-line version of the compiler:
http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app.html

It can be downloaded here:
http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/downloads/